# SharePoint 2007 Website Authentication

Tags: anonymous-authentication, windows-authentication

I've build an external facing SharePoint site and it's keeps promopting for the user the login.  How do I remove this functionality while allow internal users to log in?  Ideally, I'd like to hide the "log in" on the public facing site altogether.

I'm using SharePoint (MOSS) 2007.

Comment: Is it based on Windows Authentication? Internal Users's login to same domain as the SP site?

Comment: Yes, it's Windows based. I've isolated the problem such that it only happens when on certain sites in the drop down menu. The menu has 3 levels and it only happens when the mouse activates the 3rd level however the menu uses the same jQuery and CSS so I have no idea why this would be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem using Fiddler.  It turns out an arrow image used in the drop down menu was set to version 0.1 rather than 1.0 (ie. It wasn't approved) and thus it would force SharePoint to ask for credentials.